# Reorder array object with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to reorder this array:

```
[{ a: "v1", b: "v2"} , {a: "v3", b: "v4"}]
```

to this:

```
{a: ["v1", "v3"] , b: ["v2", "v4"]}
```

*Note: It is necessary to guarantee order, the first array element should be the first element in the array value in each key object*

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: a shorten solution

Comment: Do you accept pure js solution?

Comment: yes, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure js solution, using `Array#forEach` and `Object.keys`.

```js
var arr = [{ a: "v1", b: "v2"} , {a: "v3", b: "v4"}],
    obj = {};
    
    arr.forEach(c => Object.keys(c).forEach(function(v){
      (obj[v] || (obj[v] = [])).push(c[v]);
    }));
    
    console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

An extended Version of @Kind user's code, that also deals with objects that have different keys:

```js
function mapByKey(source){
  var result = Object.create(null);
  source.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(item == null) return;
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
      if(!(key in result)){
        //don't use sparse Arrays
        result[key] = Array(source.length).fill(undefined); 
      }

      result[key][index] = item[key];
    })
  })
  return result;
}

var array = [
  {a: "v1", b: "v2"}, 
  {a: "v3", c: "v4"}, 
  {b: "v5", c: "v7"}
];
var mapping = mapByKey(array);

console.log(mapping);

//or something funny:
console.log(mapByKey(["foo", "bar", "baz", "asdf"]));
```

The point of this version, is that even if your Array contains Objects with different keys *(like in the example, one object has `a` and `b`, one has `a` and `c` and one has `b` and `c`)*, this will always be true:

```
array[index][key] === mapping[key][index];
```

Comment: *that also deals with objects that have different keys* - my code doesn't? (:

Comment: @Kinduser, maybe I misinterpreted the OTs request for guaranteed order as a request for a strict mapping: `array[index][key] === mapping[key][index]`. That's the difference between our two codes. Your code returns a list of values by key, mine a strict mapping. Let's see what the OT actually needs.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Object.keys()` function:

```js
var arr = [{ a: "v1", b: "v2"} , {a: "v3", b: "v4"}],
    result = arr.reduce(function (r, o) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k){ (r[k])? r[k].push(o[k]) : r[k] = [o[k]]; });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lodash solution that uses the combination of [spread](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#spread) and [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) to merge all the objects with similar properties.

```
var result = _.spread(_.mergeWith)([{}].concat(data, 
  _.flow(_.ary(_.concat, 2), _.compact)
));
```

```js
var data = [{
  a: "v1",
  b: "v2"
}, {
  a: "v3",
  b: "v4"
}, {
  a: "v5",
  b: "v6",
  c: "1"
}];

var result = _.spread(_.mergeWith)([{}].concat(data, 
  _.flow(_.ary(_.concat, 2), _.compact)
));

console.log(result);
```

```css
body>div {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (short) lodash solution, using a combination of `reduce` and `mergeWith`:

```
_.reduce(data, (acc, x) => _.mergeWith(acc, x, 
                                            (obj = [], src) => obj.concat(src)),
         {});
```

Or a bit more readable:

```
const customizer = (obj = [], src) => obj.concat(src);
_.reduce(data, (acc, x) => _.mergeWith(acc, x, customizer), {});
```

Or even:

```
const customizer = (obj = [], src) => obj.concat(src);
_.reduce(data, _.partialRight(_.mergeWith, customizer), {});
```